# how can I select the array with the oldest time

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have these arras

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [TEAM] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => localhost

                )

            [Registraion] => Array
                (

                     [Registered] => 2011-09-20 09:20:51
                )

        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [TEAM] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => localhost

                )

            [Registraion] => Array
                (

                     [Registered] => 2011-09-20 09:30:51
                )


        )

[2] => Array
        (
            [TEAM] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [name] => localhost

                )

            [Registraion] => Array
                (

                     [Registered] => 2011-09-20 09:40:51
                )


        )
```

I want to get this

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [TEAM] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [name] => localhost

                    )

                [Registraion] => Array
                    (

                         [Registered] => 2011-09-20 09:20:51
                    )

            )
```

as that person is the oldest to register.

How can I get the oldest registration value?

thanks

Comment: Loop over the array and remember the id and the time of the element with the oldest time you have seen so far. At the end of the loop you know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$oldestkey = null;

foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    if (isnull($oldestkey) || ($array[$key]['Registraion']['Registered'] < $array[$oldestkey]['Registraion']['Registered']) {
         $oldestkey = $key;
    }
}
```

Note that your key `Registraion` is mis-spelled, I'm guessing it should be `Registration`? Also note that this code will not handle the case where there's multiple keys with the same registration time. It'll pick out the FIRST oldest time and return the key for that record. Any duplicate times will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Loop each item

```
 $oldest = $arr[0];
 foreach($array as $arr){ 
      if($arr["Registration"]["Registered"] < $oldest["Registration"]["Registered"])
            $oldest = $arr;
 }
```

Please use the time comparision while comparing

Answer (score 1):

```
function getOldestRecord($ar)
{
   $last_id;
   $last_time = 0;
   foreach($ar as $key => $val)
   {
      $time_stamp = strtotime($val['Registration']['Registered']);
      if($time_stamp > $last_time)
      {
         $last_time = $time_stamp;
         $last_id = $key;
      }
   }
   return $ar[$last_id];
}
```

function above accepts your array, then loops through it and compare dates, and it will return last registered user.